# mvc authorize or authenticate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Instead of using windows/forms authentication can I just use authorize attributes on the control actions that I want to restrict?

It seems to me that authorization is strictly better then authentication and is a replacement in most situations. I understand that authentication is at the web.config level and thus lets you switch pages in and out without a recompile, but if we didn't need that functionality then authorization is the way to go?

Comment: You can't authorize an anonymous user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  The Authorize attribute is used in conjunction with authentication so that non-authed users cannot run the actions decorated with the attribute.  If you use authorize and do not set up authentication, I am not sure what it would do.  I think it would use anon access.

Comment: I didn't understand the interaction of authorize and authenticate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To protect a system you need both authentication **and** authorization.

http://www.duke.edu/~rob/kerberos/authvauth.html

Comment: Authentication is the mechanism whereby systems may securely identify their users.  Authorization, by contrast, is the mechanism by which a system determines what level of access a particular authenticated user should have to secured resources controlled by the system.

Comment: @Dismissile +1. Well described. The difference between "who you are" and "what are you doing" is often misunderstood. "Identity" and "user account" are also concepts that are similarly confused. The default Microsoft Membership Providers for ASP.NET are both confusing and dated in this area. Microsoft need to go back to basics and rewrite the basic Membership providers that they ship with ASP.NET. And by simple, I don't mean Microsoft "Cardspace, Cardspace, CARDSPACE" Geneva. I mean OpenId out of the box. They should have a chat to Jeff Atwood and the SO team.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is how you determine who a user is a.k.a. Logging In.

Authorize is a Annotation for ASP .NET that says to use this part of the site you need to be authenticated.

Comment: Not only that you need to be authenticated....but that you have sufficient permissions as well (such as being an administrator to access the admin page, etc.)